# Why doesn't GNOME Shell run smoothly on my hardware?

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, gnome, performance

I'm having problems running GNOME Shell with my NVIDIA 7025/nforce 630a (on-board). The animations don't run smoothly when I configure my BIOS to give 512MB to the chipset. The only solution I've found is to change the shared RAM to 128MB. After this, the animations run well but I can only use 128MB for some applications.

- AMD Athlon 240x2 2.7GHz
- 2GB of ram

Comment: Since you have a system that uses shared system RAM for video, and it performs better with less RAM allocated to video, how much RAM is in your system total? Perhaps by increasing video RAM to 512 you are over-allocating and adding more system RAM would help.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information. **note the video section**

Answer (score 1):

You have a combination of things that can be improved. NVIDIA 7025/nforce 630a on-board video controller is "at best" a minimal performer. Recommend upgrading if at all possible.

AMD processor is a 2MB/AM3 which is not bad but if the board is a AM3 then there are other pieces that are faster than a AMD Athlon 240x2.

Mostly the GPU suffers from the nforce 630's performance. This is probably where your issues stem from. [read specs here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/mobo_gpu_features_benefits.html)

Now all that being said. I would recommend [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) as the system of choice.